# Probability Notation Confusion

Tags: conditional-probability, notation

In the following image, taken from paper on Variational Autoencoders by Dr. Kingma and Dr. Welling, it is mentioned that probability of the data points **given the parameters** factorizes into product of individual probabilities. However, it is denoted as **P{subscript theta}(D)** instead of **P(D|theta)** and it is also later referred to as likelihood. So, does **P{subscript theta}(D)** and **P(D|theta)**  mean the same and are just two ways of denoting the same thing?

> **1.6.1 Dataset**
>
> We often collect a dataset $\mathcal{D}$ consisting of $N \geq 1$ datapoints:
> \begin{equation}\mathcal{D} = \{\mathbf{x}^{(1)}, \mathbf{x}^{(2)}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}^{(N)}\} \equiv \{\mathbf{x}^{(i)}\}_{i=1}^N \equiv \mathbf{x}^{(1:N)}\end{equation}
> The datapoints are assumed to be independent samples from an unchanging underlying distribution. In other words, the dataset is assumed to consist of distinct, independent measurements from the same (unchanging) system. In this case, the observations $\mathcal{D} = \{\mathbf{x}^{(i)}\}_{i=1}^N$ are said to be *i.i.d.*, for *independently and identically distributed*. Under the same i.i.d. assumption, the probability of the datapoints given the parameters factorizes as a product of individual datapoint probabilities. The log-probability assigned to the data by the model is therefore given by:
> \begin{equation}\log p_\theta(\mathcal{D}) = \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{D}} \log p_\theta(\mathbf{x})\end{equation}

Comment: It is just a notation. If the approach is not Bayesian, conditioning upon parameters $\theta$ is not meaningful and it is more traditional to index the data density by $\theta$.

Comment: It is almost always best to accept a source's notation *as that source defines it,* regardless of any superficial similarities that notation might bear to other materials you have seen.  This quotation is clear about the meaning of its notation.